# Adding images to Access Database Vb.net - Insert into syntax error

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm quite new to Visual Basic. I'm developing a simple Student Registration System that has a profile of Students with a photo in it. I managed to get the image addition code online and I tried to figure it out and use it for my program. All is set except the sql insert statement that will insert the photo into the "Image" field of the "Students" table of my database. When I click the save button, I keep getting Insert into syntax error but I can't seem to figure out exactly what the error in the sql statement is. I would appreciate it if I can get help with it. This is the whole code for the profile but I have put a comment where the sql statement is so you can go straight there. Thanks and Thanks again

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Data.OleDb

     Public Class Profile
      Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
      Dim ds As New DataSet
      Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
      Dim sql As String
      Dim conString As String
      Dim inc As Integer
      Dim maxrows As Integer
      Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
      Dim SID As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNationality.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

End Sub
Private Sub ProfileRecords()
    txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    txtMiddleName.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    txtLastName.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(3)
    txtGender.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(4)
    txtNationality.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(5)
    txtLevel.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(6)
    txtFaculty.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(7)
    txtProgramme.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(8)
    txtAcademicPeriod.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(9)
    txtDateRegistered.Text = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(10)

    maxrows = ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows.Count

    txtFirstName.ReadOnly = True
    txtMiddleName.ReadOnly = True
    txtLastName.ReadOnly = True
    txtGender.Enabled = False
    txtFaculty.Enabled = False
    txtLevel.ReadOnly = True
    txtNationality.Enabled = False
    txtProgramme.Enabled = False
    txtAcademicPeriod.ReadOnly = True
    txtDateRegistered.ReadOnly = True



End Sub

Private Sub Profile_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SID = Login.txtstudentid.Text
    btneditcancel.Visible = False
    btneditsave.Visible = False
    btnbrowseimage.Visible = False
    txtimagepath.Visible = False

    Try
        conString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Yaw Biney\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Student Registration System\Student Registration System\StudentRegSYS.accdb"
        con = New OleDbConnection(conString)
        con.Open()
        sql = "select * from Students Where SID='" + SID + "'"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "StudentRegSYS")
        con.Close()

    Catch EXP As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(EXP.ToString)
    End Try
    con.Open()

    ProfileRecords()

    txtNationality.Items.Add("Ghanaian")
    txtNationality.Items.Add("Togolese")
    txtNationality.Items.Add("Gabonese")
    txtNationality.Items.Add("Ivorian")
    txtNationality.Items.Add("Burkinabe")
    txtNationality.Items.Add("Nigerian")
    txtNationality.Items.Add("Beninois")


    txtFaculty.Items.Add("Informatics")
    txtFaculty.Items.Add("Engineering")
    txtFaculty.Items.Add("Business")

    txtProgramme.Items.Add("Bsc. Information Technology")
    txtProgramme.Items.Add("Bsc. Telecom Engineering")
    txtProgramme.Items.Add("Bsc. Computer Engineering")
    txtProgramme.Items.Add("BA. Business Administration")
    txtProgramme.Items.Add("Diploma in Information Technology")
    txtProgramme.Items.Add("Diploma in Business Studies")


    txtwelcomemsg.Text = "Welcome " & txtLastName.Text & ", " & txtFirstName.Text & " " & txtMiddleName.Text

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMiddleName.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    btneditcancel.Visible = True
    btneditsave.Visible = True
    btnbrowseimage.Visible = True
    txtimagepath.Visible = True

    txtFirstName.ReadOnly = False
    txtMiddleName.ReadOnly = False
    txtLastName.ReadOnly = False
    txtGender.Enabled = True
    txtFaculty.Enabled = True
    txtLevel.ReadOnly = False
    txtNationality.Enabled = True
    txtProgramme.Enabled = True
    txtAcademicPeriod.ReadOnly = False
    txtDateRegistered.ReadOnly = False
End Sub

Private Sub btneditcancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btneditcancel.Click

    btneditcancel.Visible = False
    btneditsave.Visible = False
    btnbrowseimage.Visible = False
    txtimagepath.Visible = False

    txtFirstName.ReadOnly = True
    txtMiddleName.ReadOnly = True
    txtLastName.ReadOnly = True
    txtGender.Enabled = False
    txtFaculty.Enabled = False
    txtLevel.ReadOnly = True
    txtNationality.Enabled = False
    txtProgramme.Enabled = False
    txtAcademicPeriod.ReadOnly = True
    txtDateRegistered.ReadOnly = True
End Sub

Private Sub btneditsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btneditsave.Click
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)


    Try
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(2) = txtMiddleName.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(3) = txtLastName.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(4) = txtGender.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(5) = txtNationality.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(6) = txtLevel.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(7) = txtFaculty.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(8) = txtProgramme.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(9) = txtAcademicPeriod.Text
        ds.Tables("StudentRegSYS").Rows(inc).Item(10) = txtDateRegistered.Text


        da.Update(ds, "StudentRegSYS")
        MessageBox.Show("Profile updated successfully")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try




     'Error seems to be from here on going'
    Try
        Dim MemStream As New MemoryStream
        Dim DataPic_Update As Byte()
        Me.picboxprofilepic.Image.Save(MemStream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        DataPic_Update = MemStream.GetBuffer()
        MemStream.Read(DataPic_Update, 0, MemStream.Length)
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Students (Image) VALUES(@Image)", con)

        Dim photo As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Image)
        photo.Value = DataPic_Update
        cmd.Parameters.Add(photo)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record Is Added")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try

    btneditcancel.Visible = False
    btneditsave.Visible = False
    btnbrowseimage.Visible = False
    txtimagepath.Visible = False

    txtFirstName.ReadOnly = True
    txtMiddleName.ReadOnly = True
    txtLastName.ReadOnly = True
    txtGender.Enabled = False
    txtFaculty.Enabled = False
    txtLevel.ReadOnly = True
    txtNationality.Enabled = False
    txtProgramme.Enabled = False
    txtAcademicPeriod.ReadOnly = True
    txtDateRegistered.ReadOnly = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Change_Password.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnbrowseimage.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "jpeg|*.jpg|bmp|*.bmp|all files|*.*"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.picboxprofilepic.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        txtimagepath.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If

End Sub
   End Class
```

Comment: First, consider **not** saving the image to Access - it bloats the db a great deal.  Instead store the images to some folder and save the filename, changing the name to incorporate the StudentID.  If you must, then at least thumbnail the image.  Dont use GetBuffer it will bloat the db even worse; use `.ToArray`.  There is *more information* included with the exception which will give you a better idea.  You are also using the SQL Server namespace at least for `SqlDbType` which is wrong, use `OleDbType`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection